# Trying to centralize divs

Tags: html, css

im trying to centralize the DIV .dolar and .euro, but nothing that I do at all, makes it happen.
I'm copying all the html and my css bellow. Hope you can help me.

```css
    .App {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    @media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
      .App-logo {
        animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
      }
    }
    
    .App-header {
      background-color: #282c34;
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
      color: white;
    }
    
    .texto{
      place-self: flex-end;
      margin: 0px 20px 13px 20px;
    }
    
    .Real_Rapido{
      margin: auto;
      width: 900px;
    }
    
    .dolar{
      padding-top: 20%;
    }
    
    .dolar, .euro{
      display: flex;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    .euro{
      padding-top: 10%;
    }
    
    .cotacao{
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .cotacao, .simbolo{
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    .cotacao input{
      font-size: 2em;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .moeda{
      width: 150px;
      color: #778899;
    }
    
    .bandeiras{
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 100px;
      height: 68px;
      margin-top:-20px;
    }
    
    .simbolo{
      position: relative;
      color: #D3D3D3;
      width: 118px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .eua{
      background: transparent url(eua.png) no-repeat center;
      background-size: 100px;
    }
    
    .br{
      background: transparent url(brasil.png) no-repeat center;
      background-size: 100px;
    }
    
    .ue{
      background: transparent url(ue.png) no-repeat center;
      background-size: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylee.css">
    </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">
          <div class="Real_Rapido">
            <div class="dolar">
              <span class="cotacao">
                <span class="bandeiras eua"></span>
                <span class="simbolo">US$</span>
                <input type="text" class="moeda" value="1.00">
              </span>
              <span class="texto">está valendo</span>
              <span class="cotacao direita">
                <span class="bandeiras br">   </span>
                <span class="simbolo"> R$ </span>
                <input type="text" class="moeda" value="5.06">
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="euro">
              <span class="cotacao">
                <span class="bandeiras ue">   </span>
                <span class="simbolo"> € </span>
                <input type="text" class="moeda" value="1.00">
              </span>
              <span class="texto">está valendo</span>
                <span class="cotacao direita">
                <span class="bandeiras br">   </span>
                <span class="simbolo"> R$ </span>
                <input type="text" class="moeda" value="5.50">
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I think this is happening  because I used the 'flex'. But I dont know how to fix it.
If I dont use 'flex' everything brokes.
Please, dont give me just the solution, give me an explanation =)
thank you for helping

Comment: can you create a snippet for your question ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-https-1g919c?file=/index.html

thats work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "justify-content: center" on both .dolar, .euro classes.

justify-content is a css property that defines how content is displayed horizontally within a flex container.